Why is splunk xpath not able to parse my rex-extracted XML?
I am trying to parse the XML payload from my Msg Field using xpath, however I cannot get the xpath command to return any results.
Msg: {"type":"RESP_OUT","method":"SampleMethod.callName","payload":<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Request><foo><bar nickname="spock"></bar></foo><foo><bar nickname="scotty"></bar></foo></Request>,"requestEvent":true} 

I am able to extract just the XML from the message using rex:
| rex field=Msg "{\"type\":\"RESP_OUT\",\"method\":\"SampleMethod.callName\",\"payload\":(?<Payload>.*),\"requestEvent\":true}"

But when I attempt to use xpath against the Payload field, I get no results:
| xpath field=Payload outfield=Nickname "//bar/@nickname"

Any suggestions?  I don't want to have to use rex for each individual field from my XML that I need to find. Thanks!
I've tried using xpath against the rex-extracted field and | xmlkv field=Payload

I can't explain why xpath is not working for you, although it's always had its quirks.  I recommend using the newer spath command, which can parse either JSON or XML.  The syntax is a little different and I've always had better luck with it compared to xpath.
| makeresults 
| eval Msg="{\"type\":\"RESP_OUT\",\"method\":\"SampleMethod.callName\",\"payload\":<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Request><foo><bar nickname=\"spock\"></bar></foo><foo><bar nickname=\"scotty\"></bar></foo></Request>,\"requestEvent\":true}" 
``` Above just creates demo data.  Remove IRL ```
| rex field=Msg "{\"type\":\"RESP_OUT\",\"method\":\"SampleMethod.callName\",\"payload\":(?<Payload>.*),\"requestEvent\":true}"
| spath input=Payload output=Nickname path=Request.foo.bar{@nickname}

